# Does "less expensive" + "saving money" = "win-win?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, difference, phrases

I recently saw this standalone ad:
[image]
and I thought a "win-win" was something that's a "win" for two different people/groups who might otherwise be opposing each other, or at the very least, two *different* wins (especially one right after another) for the same person.
**What am I missing here?**
Do I misunderstand "win-win?"
Is there a distinction I'm missing between "less expensive" and "saving money" in this context?
Is it something else?

Comment: You are not missing anything; you understand the idiom perfectly. Either the advertising copywriter did not understand the idiom _win-win,_ or ... well, I can't think of the second alternative. Perhaps the copywriter is just a numbskull, or an executive at "SolarCity" (intercaps are _so_ 2004) insisted on the copy because he thought it was "clever."

Comment: @P.E.Dant Come on over to [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), the largest Stack Exchange site, and you'll see that CamelCase is alive and well...

Comment: My scorn for the practice exempts its use in function and argument names, where it advances intelligibility. Elsewhere, it is a stain upon the  escutcheon of marketing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding is correct. I also think this ad is not particularly clear. I also thought that this ad referred to a single "win", as in, *obviously less expensive equals saving money*. So it would seem like they are using "win-win" incorrectly. But it might not refer to the same win. On their site, I saw this:
[image]

We could give the ad the benefit of the doubt as an instance of [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese). Then judging from the first panel, I have a feeling that the ad is meant to imply that their services are less expensive *compared to their competitors' services* **and** you save on your monthly bills, for example. I think that would certainly be a *win-win*.

If we don't give them the benefit of the doubt, then it really seems like an incorrect usage of "win-win" and an attempt to grab the reader's attention.

Comment: But this does not satisfy the condition implied in the idiom. The two wins must be somehow apposite to each other. Where is the apposition between _paying less_ and _saving money?_ Both benefits accrue to the customer!

Comment: I think because you save money in two different ways, it counts as a win-win. I suppose I'm taking _win-win_ to mean that all (the two) options are beneficial, and in this case they are. The option of choosing this company is beneficial and the option of going solar is beneficial.

Comment: _Win-win_ does _not_ mean "both options are beneficial." That describes just **two wins.**  There is no apposition of interests there: **both accrue to the customer!** Example of a real win-win: a clownfish and anemone living in near symbiosis.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. [win-win](http://www.yourdictionary.com/win-win): designating or of a situation, course of action, etc. having multiple possible outcomes, any of which may be interpreted as successful or positive. This does not preclude a single person from having a win-win. Is that what you're getting at? I think OP made that more or less clear.

Comment: A win-win in the real sense of the idiom can only apply to a single person when the context includes **competing interests,** both of which are satisified to some degree. It appears that the point of the idiom escaped not just the copywriter. It also escaped the clown who wrote that entry in "yourdictionary.com." As Wikipedia has it: _...a win–win strategy is a **conflict resolution process** that aims to accommodate all **disputants.**_ (My emphasis.) In a zero sum game, my gain is your loss. In a win-win, this expectation is up-ended: both sides win.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the definition on yourdictionary.com isn't any less real than the dominating meaning or the entry given in Wikipedia. _Win-win_ can also be used to refer to just one person. I've heard people say "That's a win-win for me!" (where multiple benefits solely go to the speaker), for example, and that doesn't seem any less real or incorrect than the dominating definition. It seems prevalent enough in my opinion to warrant a dictionary entry and to be deemed "real".

Comment: I suppose it is normal for an idiom to drift from its original, useful, and precise meaning (which justifies its status as an idiom) to an amorphous, vague, meaningless blob of words which, in this case, apparently now means only _two or more real good things for some guy._ This is what has become of _carrot and stick,_ for instance. People who don't know what a mule is now use the idiom as if the idea is that the mule is _struck_ with the stick. Well, as the saying goes: _sic transit Gloria Swanson._